# SQL Trigger not working #1407 - Bad SQLSTATE: 'Approved!'

Tags: mysql

This is the trigger I created recently. What it is supposed to do:

If a customer doesn't have a Valid driving license, they  cannot be approved. If they do, they are approved! The error I get in PhpMyAdmin

> 1407 - Bad SQLSTATE: 'Approved!'

```
 DELIMITER //
    CREATE TRIGGER check_licence AFTER INSERT ON customers
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN 
        IF NEW.valid_licence = 'Yes' THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE 'Approved!' set message_text='You need to have a valid driving licence.';
        ELSEIF NEW.valid_licence > 'Unapproved';
        END IF;
    END;
    //
    DELIMITER;
```

Comment: SQLSTATE value can indicate errors, warnings, or “not found.” The first two characters of the value indicate its error class

Comment: Does it compile at all? Where is the `THEN` branch of the `ELSEIF`?